# Creating a button which links to another page in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently doing an exercise in creating a web app in reactjs, the task is to create a button which when pressed "the app goes to a new route " - so basically create a new page.
Ive tried the usual html buttons / href but this isn't working.

The code where i'm assuming the button would go looks like this:

```
`return (
    <div className="jokeSection">
      <h1>Chuck norris jokes</h1>
      <h3>{joke}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => newJoke()}>Click here for a chuckle</button>
      <button a href="search.js">Search for joke</button>
    </div>
  )`
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Link` tag of the `react-router` that is a very popular third party library of **React**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'; // IF IS REACT-WEB
import { Link } from 'react-router-native'; // IF IS REACT-NATIVE

// YOUR CODE

return (
<div className="jokeSection">
  <h1>Chuck norris jokes</h1>
  <h3>{joke}</h3>
  <button onClick={() => newJoke()}>Click here for a chuckle</button>
  <Link to="/search"><button>Search for joke</button></Link>
</div>
)
```

For more information and how to install the React-Router please follow this [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

You use the 'react-router-dom' package to route to new component, for which you can declare in a seperate file:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Search from './search'

  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
      <Link to="/search">Contact</Link>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

The Route component will declare the route, the Link component will display it.The file search.js must contain Search component ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native try to use **`react-router-native`**, if browser based use **`react-router-dom`** for routing purpose

To do navigation on button click you can do with this

`<button onClick={() => {this.props.history.push("/path_of_the_page");}}>Click here for a chuckle</button>` if it is class component

or you can just change `props.history.push("/path_of_the_page")` without **`this`**  in functional component. But you have to make sure Route is there

**[here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/quick-start)** you can get example on routing from one component/page to another